# How can I get the hardware's temperatures using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, temperature

is there any way to get the temperature and the usages of computer components (CPU, RAM, GPU) using VB.NET?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several resources easily found through google regarding probing thermal sensors through amongst other WMI. One such example for [VB .NET is here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18ce0701-e87d-4414-a8b5-8be3908a21b8/reading-cpu-temperature-wmi)

For reference, here's an example snippet:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _

            "root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature")



        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()

            Dim temp As Double = CDbl(queryObj("CurrentTemperature"))

            temp = (temp - 2732) / 10.0

            MessageBox.Show(temp.ToString)

        Next

    Catch err As ManagementException

        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I saw this code also on another page but it give me the same an error: not supported.

Comment: `temp = (temp - 2732) / 10.0`

Is current temperature measured in 10ths of a degree Kelvin?  Measuring in Kelvin I understand; but measuring in 10ths of a degree seems an odd choice.

Comment: As noted in the article, not all mainboards support direct WMI calls, but require .DLLs from the manufacturer. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19520825-b1fc-4778-8704-c492124bc029/getting-cpu-temp?forum=vblanguage)