# How can I get the standard GPU temp in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, gpu

In visual basic and not C# how can I get the GPU temp. Like (32 C) I'm making a system monitor for a school project and I need help

Comment: Why not c#? Do you have some C# code already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963295/how-can-i-get-the-hardwares-temperatures-using-vb-net